# Threaded, incremental CLI/comand line windows FTP program

Tags: backup, ftp, cloud-storage

I need something that takes comands for incrementally copying an entire folder with threaded file transferring. Bonkey does not threading. My host caps me at 100kbps per thread.

I am trying to do FTP back ups and the people at filezilla absolutly refuse to implement automation features. Filezilla can have up to 10 threads and has decent incermental transferring.

Synkron is fantastic for automatically syncronizing things back and foward, but on FTP support.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! But: this question was only viewed 2 times, and already has an accepted answer...? That keeps possible better answers away, if you'd ask me. (Also, the word "best" might make the question off-topic here anyhow, this not being a discussion forum.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline) could get you going far.

[RoboCopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) might be an option too.

If above tools don't contain threads, then I don't know any multithreaded solutions.